# Bulma flexbox column falling of page

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

I'm creating a simple 2 column layout. The left column should be narrow and contains a vertical navigation bar, the right column will contain the main content of the site. I'm using bulma-css columns to create this layout.

The problem that I'm encountering is that depending on the horizontal windows size, part of the right side of the second column is falling off the page. So this column is not scaling appropriately.

Below is a minimal example that illustrates the problem. Depending on window size the button will (partially) fall off the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-narrow">
        <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="button is-primary is-pulled-right">button</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Good expected behaviour:

[image]

Bad:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem is your `.container` class in the second column which has a `width`...better or remove it and use `.is-one-third` class in the first column to make it smaller or other **[[bulma grid column classes]](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/sizes/)**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css">
<div class="columns is-mobile">
  <div class="column is-one-third">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p class="button is-primary is-pulled-right">button</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not my problem, the problem is when the columns are still next to each other, for some windows sizes part of the right column isn't visible anymore. The button that is aligned to the right for example will not be visible anymore.

Comment: @jonas87 try to remove `.container` from second column...check updated answer....

Comment: removing the .container fixes the problem indeed! However, I would like some kind of padding in the second column, which the container provided. What would be a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: @jonas87 BTW container does not have any paddings...if you want to add padding, add a custom class to the second column and then apply some padding form css